# setState in react it seems that it delete all state content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote an object style and I was calling it in style of any element.
It was cool tell i wanted to edit one style value of some element, so I tried to change it like

```
onClick={{cardStyle.li.backgroundColor : "black }}
```

But that gave me a read only error, so I put the `cardStyle` object in state in order using `setState`, and now when i try to change `anyvalue` using `setState`, it seems that it only puts that value and deleted everything from it

This is the code:

```
    import React from "react";
    
    
    export default class CardInfo extends React.Component
    {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
    
            this.state = { cardStyle : {
                ul : {
                    width         : '80%',
                    margin        : '5% 10%',
                    listStyleType : "none", 
                },
                li :{
                    width         :  "30%",
                    border        : " 4px solid rgb(0, 0, 0 , 0.6) ",
                    borderRadius  : "7%",
                    textAlign     : "center",
                    paddingTop    : "3%",
                    marginRight   : '1%',
                    float         : 'left',
                    backgroundColor : this.props.Fname === "MUHAMMAD"  ? "rgb(255, 10, 92 , .7)" : "white",
                },
                img : {
                    width : " 80%",
                    borderRadius  : "7%",
                    
                },
                on : {backgroundColor : "black"}
            }}
        }
        render()
        { 
            
        
            
            return <ul  style={this.state.cardStyle.ul}>
                     <li style={this.state.cardStyle.li} 
                                onClick={() =>this.setState({cardStyle:{li:{backgroundColor : "grey"}}})} >
                        <img style={this.state.cardStyle.img} src={this.props.img} alt="lilpic" />
                        <h2>{this.props.Fname}</h2>
                        <p>{this.props.quetes}</p>
                        <p>{this.props.phone}</p>
                     </li>
    
                </ul>
    
        
        }
    }
```

[image: after click]

Comment: Your `setState` call overwrites everything. What you put in there as `cardStyle:` becomes the new `this.state.cardStyle`. If you want to update just one property you need to compose the new state by merging the current state and the new property. The basic idea is `this.setState({ cardStyle: { ...this.state.cardStyle, li: { ... } })`

Comment: Duplicate: [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

You are changing state and overriding it with new values, instead you should override the property you want and give rest of the properties as well. So replace your on click this.setState with

`this.setState({cardStyle:{  ...this.state.cardStyle, li:{backgroundColor : "grey"}}})} >`

Comment: thank u for the answer , but i didnt understand what are the  {  ... } for .

Comment: it is now deleting all the values of li only

Comment: Create a codesandbox for this so i can verify

Comment: try this tho
```this.setState({cardStyle:{  ...this.state.cardStyle, li:{...this.state.cardStyle.li, backgroundColor : "grey"}}})} > ```

Comment: {...} means that you are giving all of the other properties of the object. If you have an object like this ```let someObj = {prop1 : '', prop2: ''}``` then if you want to assign some value to ```prop1``` then you will do something like this ```someObj.prop1 = 'some value'``` . Now in your are you have an state object and if you do something like this then thats not right because you have setState. Which in our example of assigning new val to prop1 be as follows ```someObj = {prop1:'some value', prop2:''}``` if you don't write prop2 here then it will be deleted so you have to explicitly give it

Comment: We can also write our ```someObj = {prop1:'some value', prop2:''}``` into something like this. ```someObj = {...someObj, prop1 : 'some value'}```. What this ```...``` is doing is giving our object previous properties so they don't get deleted. So in a way our  ```someObj = {...someObj, prop1 : 'some value'}``` will be converted into  ```someObj = {prop1 :  '' , prop2 : '' , prop1 : 'some value'}```. Notice that ```prop1``` is given twice and the last ```prop1``` is overriding the first one. I hope this clears everything for you. I am sorry if i explained bad. Take a look at the link below

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax